# How do I import a forked repo from github?

Tags: reactjs, git, github, fork, git-fork

I forked [TimboKZ's Chonky] and made some changes to it to suit my project. (link: https://github.com/TimboKZ/Chonky) I followed every step that [this article](https://app.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-use-forked-npm-dependencies) says. when I run npm i, my terminal returns some error like this:

```
PS C:\Users\lifan\Desktop\Ubiq\New folder> npm i
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\chonky\packages\chonky" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\lifan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-11T23_14_30_825Z-debug.log
```

And this is how my package.json looks like:

```
"chonky": "https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky.git",
"chonky-icon-fontawesome": "https://github.com/Lethees/Chonky.git",
```

What should I do to successfully import the forked repo as a dependency? I noticed that TimboKZ has both 'Chonky' and 'Chonky-icon-fontawesome' in his 'package' folder, which are the two dependencies I want to import. Each dependency has a package.json. could it be something related to the errors I am getting?

Comment: Please include code and results as text directly in the question, not as images.

Comment: What about running the commands outside of the `packages` directory?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Just updated

Comment: @dan1st I am not sure what you mean. i ran the commands on the New Folder